# Cannot coerce class ""histogram"" to a data.frame error in when plotting a graph in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have the following data frame that I extract from google analytics

```
ga_data <- google_analytics_4(viewId = my_id,
                          date_range = c(Sys.Date()-7, Sys.Date()-1),
                          metrics = c("sessions","pageviews",
                                      "entrances","bounces"),
                          dimensions = c("date","deviceCategory",
                                         "channelGrouping"),
                          anti_sample = TRUE)
```

Now I want to show a graph of ga_data in a Shiny application. Therefore I include the following code:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Shiny Text"),
  sidebarLayout(
   sidebarPanel(
    selectInput(inputId = "dataset",
              label = "Choose a dataset:",
              choices = c("ga_data")),

    numericInput(inputId = "obs",
               label = "Number of observations to view:",
               value = 10)
   ),

   mainPanel(   

    verbatimTextOutput("summary"),  
    tableOutput("view")

  )
 )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

 ga_data <- google_analytics_4(viewId = 156004565,
                            date_range = c(Sys.Date()-7, Sys.Date()-1),
                            metrics = c("sessions","pageviews",
                                        "entrances","bounces"),
                            dimensions = c("date","deviceCategory",
                                           "channelGrouping"),
                            anti_sample = TRUE)


  datasetInput <- reactive({
    switch(input$dataset,
       "ga_data" = ga_data)
  })


   output$view <- renderTable({

  hist(ga_data$sessions)


 })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

However when I run it I get the following error:

```
cannot coerce class ""histogram"" to a data.frame
```

But this is strange cause when I want to make normal plot of the dataframe it does work. So the problem probably has to do with Shiny.

Any thoughts on what can go wrong here?

Comment: Why are you using `renderTable()` with `tableOutput` to draw the plot? Those are for tables. Don't you want `renderPlot()` with `plotOutput`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I don't have `googleAnalyticsR` set up, I reduced your problem to his simple app.

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
  fluidPage(tableOutput("table")),
  server = function(input, output, session){
    output$table <- renderTable({hist(mtcars$mpg)})
  }
)
## Warning: Error in as.data.frame.default: cannot coerce class ""histogram"" to a 
##   data.frame
```

The problem here is that you try to render a plot using `renderTable`. If you use `renderPlot` instead, everything works.

```
shinyApp(
  fluidPage(plotOutput("plot")),
  server = function(input, output, session){
    output$plot <- renderPlot({hist(mtcars$mpg)})
  }
)
```